# insertion sort algorithm in Objective-C to implement in iphone

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to sort 15 random numbers using Objective-C in the code shown below. The code is not working as planned. I took the concept from the the insertion sort C code. The 15 random numbers are generating properly but the sort is not working.

**C code:**

```
int i, j, index;
for (i = 1; i < array_size; ++i)
{
  index = a[i];
  for (j = i; j > 0 && a[j-1] > index; j--)
    a[j] = a[j-1];

  a[j] = index;
}
```

**Objective-C code:**

```
-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender
{
  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) 
  {
    [array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",array);
  {
    int i, j;
    id index;
    for (i = 1; i < 15; ++i)
    {
      index = [array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i]; //   a[i];
      for (j = i; j > 0 && [array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j-1] > index; j--)
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [array objectAtIndex: (j-1)]];

      [array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j] == index ;
    }
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",array);   
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're writing the sort yourself instead of using, say, one of the `sortedArrayUsing...` methods on `NSArray`? Unless this is a strict requirement, such as for a homework assignment, there is rarely a reason to implement your own sorting.

Comment: thanks , yes i need to sort using the above code and not internal functions to see how much time it takes certain algorithms to execute

Comment: Premature optimization or research for fun/education? In any case you won't get any reliable data (or performance problems) from only 15 numbers.

Comment: yes correct but 15 numbers is track the log file only if works correctly the numbers will be chnaged

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing pointers, which is just sorting your array by the memory addresses of your objects, not their actual value.

```
index = [array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i]; //   a[i];
[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j-1] > index
```

You need to get the primitive integer value of the NSNumber:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:20] != 20; // This is wrong.
[[NSNumber numberWithInt:20] intValue] == 20; // This is correct.
```

Here's your code, with revisions:

```
-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender
{
  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) 
  {
    [array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",array);
  {
    int i, j;
    id index;
    for (i = 1; i < 15; ++i)
    {
      index = [[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i] intValue]; //   a[i];
      for (j = i; j > 0 && [[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j-1] intValue] > index; j--)
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [array objectAtIndex: (j-1)]];

      [[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j] intValue] == index ;
    }
  }
  NSLog(@"%@",array);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that the algorithm itself does not make much sense.

This line:

```
[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j] == index ;
```

Should be:

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:index]; //yes again
```

Try this way, with modern syntax:

```
-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    {
        [array addObject: @(arc4random()%200)];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",array);

    NSUInteger i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        NSNumber *current = array[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && [array[j-1] unsignedIntegerValue] > [current unsignedIntegerValue]; j--)
            array[j] = array[j-1];

        array[j] = current;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
}
```

Run the code and see the result.